# Are Anti-CSRF tokens stored on client-side, server-side, or both?

Tags: session, cookies, jwt, xss, csrf

I'm creating a React Js website with a Node.js backend. I've been attempting to figure out a user authentication implementation to prevent CSRF attacks however I'm really confused about where to store Anti-CSRF tokens.

My thought process of a secure implementation is as follows...

1. User submits request to login with credentials.
2. Credentials are authenticated.
3. Server creates session.
4. Server creates JWT to use as Anti-CSRF token.
5. Server stores JWT (Anti-CSRF token) in session storage.
6. Server sends response to client.

   - Response has header to store session ID in HttpOnly cookie on client-side.
   - Response payload includes JWT (Anti-CSRF token).
7. Client receives response.
8. HttpOnly cookie holding session ID is stored on client-side.
9. Client stores JWT (Anti-CSRF token) in localStorage.

I figure when a user needs to request information, the client can send the JWT (Anti-CSRF token) via a header or payload, and the session ID will be sent automatically due to it being a cookie. Then, the server can check if the JWT (Anti-CSRF token) exists in the session storage.

I know that the JWT (Anti-CSRF token) will need to be refreshed at some point.

My confusion is due to storing the JWT (Anti-CSRF token) on the client side. I keep reading that it should only be stored on the server. But if it's only stored on the server it doesn't seem to be doing anything at all.

I thought of using both cookies and localStorage because it seems that if a request to the server needs both a HttpOnly cookie and something from localStorage to send back an "authorized" response, an attacker would need to both successfully ride a session and successfully implement an XSS attack to get the Anti-CSRF token.

I just started learning about CSRF and XSS recently so I could be completely wrong and there could be a huge flaw in my implementation that I'm missing. But my main question is... don't Anti-CSRF tokens need to be stored on the client AND the server?

Answer (score 2):

They are also called "CSRF Tokens". When a client requests for a form (e.g. bank login page), server generates the tokens and passes them to client and when the client fills the form, client passes CSRF token along with the completed form. Server verifies the token value and if it matches, request is fulfilled. CSRF tokens are stored on server-side  in synchronizer token pattern.